# Chathead to stay foreground when open a new activity

Tags: android

Normal function of chatHead is that it appears on all the activities whichever is opened. I would like the chatHead to stay in foreground when i open a new activity. For example, when i open another application like contacts or Message chatHead should not appear. Is this possible? Please advise with code thanks

Fly class:

```
public class Fly extends Service {


private WindowManager windowManager;
private ImageView chatHead;

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override 
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    windowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);

    chatHead = new ImageView(this);

    chatHead.setImageResource(R.drawable.floating);

    final WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,

            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,

            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,

            PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

    params.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.LEFT;
    params.x = 0;
    params.y = 100;


    windowManager.addView(chatHead, params);



    try {
        chatHead.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            private WindowManager.LayoutParams paramsF = params;
            private int initialX;
            private int initialY;
            private float initialTouchX;
            private float initialTouchY;

            @Override public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

                    // Get current time in nano seconds.

                    initialX = paramsF.x;
                    initialY = paramsF.y;
                    initialTouchX = event.getRawX();
                    initialTouchY = event.getRawY();
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    paramsF.x = initialX + (int) (event.getRawX() - initialTouchX);
                    paramsF.y = initialY + (int) (event.getRawY() - initialTouchY);
                    windowManager.updateViewLayout(chatHead, paramsF);
                    break;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }

}



@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (chatHead != null) windowManager.removeView(chatHead);
    //windowManager.removeView(chatHead);


}

}
```

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();

    if(bundle != null && bundle.getString("LAUNCH").equals("YES")) {
        startService(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Fly.class));
    }

    Button launch = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    launch.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startService(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Fly.class));
        }
    });

    Button stop = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
    stop.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            stopService(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Fly.class));
        }
    });

}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();

    if(bundle != null && bundle.getString("LAUNCH").equals("YES")) {
        startService(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Fly.class));
    }
    super.onResume();
}
```

protected void onPause() {

```
    if (chatHead != null) windowManager.removeView(chatHead);

    super.onPause();

}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your chathead is added to the `WindowManager`, which appears above everything else in your application, including newly launched activities. You should manually remove the chatHead in the `onPause` function of an `Activity` by messaging the `Service` if you do not want it to appear outside of that certain `Activity`.

This code will need to run in the `Service` when it receives the message from the activity.

```
if (chatHead != null) {
    windowManager.removeView(chatHead);
}
```

You can also save the parameters of the `chatHead` view and re-add it back by sending a different message to the `Service` in the `Activity`'s `onResume`.

Please see the [Android Service documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#RemoteMessengerServiceSample) for how to set up messaging.

---

Another alternative is to not use a service at all, but to move all of the code from it into your activity. Then, you can directly control whether the chatHead is displayed from the `Activity`'s `onPause` and `onResume` functions. Please see [this helpful tutorial on Pausing and Resuming an Activity](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/pausing.html).

Comment: Not sure what is going wrong. I have included the code in onPause() in the fly class however there is no change :(  Am i doing it correctly?

Comment: Since you are using a `Service`, you will want to add something to your `Activity`'s `onPause` that will tell the `Service` to remove the chatHead.

Comment: I have added in Activity and there is no change. Please check the edited code in Activity. Sorry I am new to Android so let me know what am i doing wrong. Thanks in advance

Comment: Your `Activity` need to tell your `Service` to remove the view in `onPause` instead of attempting to call `removeView`. `removeView` should be called from the `Service`, not the `Activity`. What happens when you hit the stop button?

Comment: chatHead disappears when the stop button is hit.

Comment: Ok, so try sending a message from the `Activity`'s onPause to your `Service`. When the `Service` receives that message, it should call the same code as the line in its `onDestroy` function that removes the chatHead. I will edit my answer in a few minutes.